# swiping between records with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to build a view where customers can swipe side to side between potentially thousands of records, so my thought was to use a UIScrollView with 3 view controllers to display the details, so there is always a view controller off screen to the left with the previous record and a view controller to the right with the next record.

What I need help with is the logic to move the view controllers around in the scroll view.

I've seen examples online but they mostly seem buggy, or they allocate 1 view controller for each piece of data they want to display, but obviously I don't want to put thousands of view controllers in memory.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good solution for this situation?

I appreciate any help...

Comment: A UICollectionView is a far better solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation for `UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html), which can be initialized to scroll horizontally between its pages. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) if you need help getting started.

Comment: Can a `UIPageViewController` be used for thousands of pages?

Comment: @rmaddy yes. If `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` is implemented, VC's that are no longer visible, are destroyed or recycled, as needed, automatically. It's similar to a `UITableView` in that sense. More about the protocol [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPageViewControllerDelegate).